# How to calculate this Integral with E?

Tags: calculus

i have just this question this integral equal to what ?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{E}\frac{\mathbb{1}_{[-2,2]}(t)}{\pi\sqrt{4-t^2}}dt$$ where $E\in[-2,2]$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Split the integral up into sections where the integrand is zero and where it is not.
Then use the antiderivative
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-t^2}}\,\mathrm{d}t = \arcsin\left(\frac12 t\right) $$

Comment: thanks for unswering but we will have 
$$\int_{-2}^{E}\frac{dt}{\pi\sqrt{4-t^2}}$$ where $E\in[-2,2]$ 
i want to use $arccos$ then what we will have as a result , this integral is bodring me :) because i think there is a problem when $E<0$ and when $E>0$